# Techniques for translating code by hand

Tags: c#, java, c++, porting

In case I want to translate a program's code in a different programming language, I have these options: to use special software or to do it on my own (please tell me if there are other ways).

Personally I'm a beginner in C++, C# and Java. I'm not familiar with other languages. I'd like to try to do a translation of one of my C++ programs to C# and/or Java. But before doing that I'd like to learn about a technique or two about translating. I'd like to learn it from someone who is familiar with such thing.

So, can you tell me techniques for translating code from one programming language to another? And if there is something that I should know before I start translating, please tell me.

Comment: What is the difference between your first and third options? (By the way, this process is generally called "porting" - though that term also applies to using the same language to adapt a programme for a different operating system or device.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Learn both languages. Understand each language's idioms and philosophy. Acquaint yourself with common coding styles and design patterns.
2. Read your source program, and understand what it is doing.
3. Think about how you would express the same overall goals in the target language, using the knowledge and experience gained from (1).
4. Rewrite the program in the target language.

(Counter-example: Your source is Java, and you see `String a = new String;`. You open C++ and say, `std::string * a = new std::string;`. *Wrong,* go back to (1).)

Comment: #2 cannot be understated. I can't tell you how many translations I've seen that were very close, but the problem of not knowing what the original program was doing caused HUGE problems!

Comment: @Aleks: If you're porting from Lisp to Fortran, you'll probably just have to write it from scratch. Between C++ and Java you might be able to copy a couple of code snippets over, and maybe some of the class hierarchy, but that should only be an optional convenience. There is absolutely no way around #2+#3. The counter-example shows how blind copying might actually be *harmful*.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the worst C# code I've seen was written by programmers that were thinking in C or C++ while writing C# syntax.

C# and Java are fundamentally different from C++. I don't like the term "translating" because this is the wrong attitude. You actually need to rewrite the program after you've learned how to think in the terms of the new language.

Answer (score 2):

There are tools, but I never find one that's perfect. At least if it's convertible syntactically, libraries would be a problem. I prefer to have deep enough knowledge between the languages (and of course, the project being converted), and convert everything by hand. The advantages of this would be you could create a clone of the project, using each language's best techniques (that may be either impossible or not optimal in other languages). The disadvantages are, however, you might be doing something wrong doing the conversion (causing incompatible end result) and it's slower.

Answer (score 1):

If you are into Test Driven Development then you have all the tests for the original implementation.  Just keep coding in the new language until you pass all the tests once again.  Don't worry too much about [Kerrek SB's counterexample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8866543/348975).  If and when you run into problems like that, just write more tests.

On the other hand, if you don't already have a suite of tests, then why are you wasting time on porting when you should be testing.

Comment: You might be porting legacy code into an environment in which testing is easier - e.g. Delphi 5 to C# or something like that. Porting and adding unit tests as you go can work quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a hedeque to "translate" it by yourself, if there is a software that can do it for you? Unless if there is a special purpose for having that skill of translate from one language to another....
Pay attention that not all languages have the same computable power,therefore it may not work sometimes....
Perhaps it would be better to stay focus on one main language.

Comment: Nah. By hand will more fun and more reliable (according to the other answers). But it's good be familiar with more than one language, because different companies work with different technologies (that require different languages), and different languages have different purposes. It's true that there are many different languages, but I'd like to be able to use some of the most popular.